# Default to PHP extension on web server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there a way a .htaccess file can be written so that

```
http://www.mysite.com/about
```

loads `about.php`

and the same goes for any file?

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ $1.php
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does your rewrite do? How does it fail, I mean?

Comment: the rewrite rule looks fine. Just to confirm, you are running Apache web server, right. This technique obviously won't work with IIS.

Comment: @Michael it doesn't do anything - it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Spudley yes it is a Apache server.

Comment: @Rio try removing the `^` from the beginning of the match expression.

Comment: @Michael it gives me a 500 error if I do that.

Comment: @Rio and what does your error log say about the 500 error? That's your clue...

Answer (score 3):

This is the most common rule (utilising **mod_rewrite** -- *make sure it is loaded and enabled*) -- it will ensure that such .php file does exist before rewriting (yes, it's a bit slower but safer):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# add .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

---

Alternatively just use this:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This will turn on "content negotiation". But it has some cons.

**For example:** let's assume you have `hello.html` & `hello.php` in your website root folder. If you request `example.com/hello`, with that option enabled Apache will look for alternative names (same name but different extensions) and will serve either `hello.html` or `hello.php` (I cannot tell which one will be preferred).

But if you only have 1 file with such unique name (e.g. `hello.php` ONLY) then no problems here at all.

Comment: I tried exactly what you said on http://www.justnear.me/about and it doesn't seem to work (where about.php does).

Comment: 1) Are you on your own server .. or shared hosting? 2) Please double check/confirm with hosting company that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled and 3) .htaccess files are enabled (some hosting companies disabling them for security and performance purposes). 4) Check your Apache's error log for possible error messages. The rule and alternative approach are **definitely** working solutions -- it has to be your specific Apache configuration/setup.

Comment: Also ... do you have other rewrite rules in place maybe? They may interfere with this rule (it all depends on your rules and their order).